# Modelagem com Code First para que possa trocar de banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Se eu gerar meu banco de dados para o MySQL usando o conceito de Code First é possível alterar futuramente para SQL Server com relativa facilidade? Precisa mudar as classes ou apenas o *config* e o *provider*?

Comment: Até onde sei, o Entity Framework abstrai o banco de dados completamente. Alterar o banco deve ser tão simples quanto alterar a string de conexão no web.config (e referenciar as DLL's que tenham os providers corretos).

Comment: Pensei nisso mesmo. Se for só isso é bacana.

Comment: Usando Code First as suas classes gera o banco, é como se fazia em Clipper, vai criando as tabelas e campos de acordo com a necessidade do sistema, pode até ser produtivo mais eu acho ruim isso.

Comment: Quando se faz a modelagem do banco de dados se tem uma visão geral do sistema, dos relacionamentos, se o mesmo consegue atender as necessidades, relatórios e possíveis problemas, você já parte para a programação com um modelo pronto.

Comment: Quanto a usar mais de 1 banco, se você usar ORM ele vai levar para dentro do sistema as características particulares de cada banco, não e tão simples de migra de banco e vai precisar manter mais de 1 versão do sistema,

Comment: as vantagens da utilização de ORM desaparecem com o aumento da complexidade pois é necessário promover uma quebra da abstração forçando o desenvolvedor a lidar com SQL.

Comment: Só sei que chamar o EF de "lixo" só pode ser elogio ao EF...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia do Entity Framework é essa mesmo, você desenvolve de uma forma independente do banco de dados. Tem até algumas facilidades para fazer a migração.

Isto não quer dizer que qualquer código que você faça será bem trocado sem maiores problemas. No básico a transição deve ser suave. Se começar fazer operações muito personalizadas usando coisas muito específicas de um banco de dados que não pode ser facilmente reproduzido por outro banco aí pode ter problemas de performance ou mesmo nem funcionar como espera.

Em geral o modelo não precisa ser mudado nada, mas pode precisar de alguma adaptação. Um índice muito bom em um banco de dados pode não ser tão adequado em outro. A estrutura física em um DB pode não ser a ideal em outra. Não quer dizer que não funcionará, mas adaptações ajudarão. As consultas e manipulações podem precisar de mais adaptações para tudo ficar em ordem.

A qualidade do *provider* do banco de dados para o Entity Framework pode fazer diferença.

Comment: Show. Como você comentou entendo que deve ter situações específicas que podem exigir um pouco mais de mudanças mas se no geral o EF conseguir resolver a maioria dos casos pretendo seguir esse caminho. Ainda não escolhi o provider, mas a ideia é começar com MySQL e em breve migrar para SQLServer e ver como se comporta. Obrigado